# Maven: Aggregation vs. Dependency

Tags: java, maven-2, dependencies, aggregation

I'm very new to Maven and am just now trying to set up my first project tree. I'm struggling to understand the difference between two alternatives:

I have jar and war projects (two each) that i want to bundle. Traditionally I'd just create an ear project that has all four of them as dependencies.

Now I read about the aggregation of poms and am not sure what to do any more (see http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation). Should I create an aggregateted POM with the four projects?

I guess basically my question is: What's the big difference between a module and a dependency, if the dependency is one of my "own" projects.

Comment: the convention at SO is to use the tag maven-2, unless you're referring to the (dead) maven version 1. It's a nuisance, if you ask me, but that's the way it is. Changed that for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A module is just a way of organizing things.

In a multi-module build, you can build an entire tree of artifacts in one step (remember the [Joel Test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html)). However, each of these will be an individual artifact, which can individually be referenced as a dependency.

Here is a sample layout, packaging in parentheses.

```
root (pom)
    - project1 (jar)
    - project2 (war) -> references project1 as dependency
    - project3 (jar)
    - project4 (war) -> references project3 as dependency
    - project5 (ear) -> references project2 and project4 as dependency
```

call `mvn install` in the root directory to build the entire tree.

The assumption here is that project1 is only used by project2 and project3 is only used by project4. Otherwise here is a more complex scenario.

```
root (pom)
    - project1 (jar)
    - project2 (jar)
    - project3 (war) -> references project1 and project2 as dependency of scope provided
    - project4 (war) -> references project1 and project2 as dependency of scope provided
    - project5 (ear) -> references project1 through project4 as dependency
```

So, modules take away the work of building several projects independently, but you still need to manage your dependencies yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Just to make it clear: If, in your example, I would not use a 'root' project but would just build project5 (i.e. 'mvn install' there), then it would _not_ automatically recompile projects 1-4, right? I guess that's what I falsely assumed and what lead to my confusion.

Comment: exactly. maven works nowhere but underneath the current directory. it will resolve other artifacts from the local or remote repository, but it will not re-build them unless they are inside the current tree.